# Default new Github repository to private

Tags: github

I'm using a free personal Github account. How to default new repository visibility to private instead of public?

Comment: How are you creating the repositories?  If you're using the API, it's always possible to specify explicitly, but otherwise, I think you always have to choose.

Comment: I'm creating them by hand off of a private template, and I find it pretty stupid that the default visibility for a repo created off of a private template is public